# How to create a datetime object given seconds since unix epoch?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pytz

There seems to be a lot of confusion online on doing a very basic thing: create a datetime object with UTC timezone given seconds since unix epoch in the UTC timezone.  Basically, I always want to work in absolute time/UTC.

I'm using python 3.5 (the latest right now) and want to simply get a `datetime` object in the context of UTC (+0/Zulu offset) from a floating point value of elapsed seconds since 1970 Jan 01.

This is wrong since the first time is created in my local timezone, and then I attempt to switch to UTC.

```
import datetime
import pytz
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(my_seconds).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python provided the method `utcfromtimestamp` just for that case. [utcfromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

```
import datetime

seconds = 0
utcdate_from_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `my_seconds` is a POSIX timestamp then to convert it to `datetime` in Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

utc_dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=my_seconds)
utc_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(my_seconds, timezone.utc)
naive_utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(my_seconds)
```

If your local timezone is "right" (non-POSIX) then only the first formula is correct (the others interpret `my_seconds` as TAI timestamp with `datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 10)` TAI epoch in this case).

[The first formula is more portable and may support a wider input range than the others.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

The results of the 1st and 2nd expressions may differ due to [rounding errors on some Python versions](http://bugs.python.org/issue23517).

The 2nd and 3rd calls should differ only by `tzinfo` attibute (the latter returns a naive datetime object (`.tzinfo is None`)). You should prefer timezone-aware datetime objects, to avoid ambiguity.